# Certificate error when posting with guzzle on D8

Tags: guzzle, drupal-8

Using the code below on D8 to post a form, I get the following error :

```
cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\common\cert\cacert.pem CApath: none (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

My question is how can I modify this code to not verify or how can I set a certificate so that I won't get this error.  thanks

```
$url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  $client = \Drupal::httpClient();

  $post_data = array('color' => 'red');
  $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
    'body' => rawData($post_data),
  ]);
  $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
  $status = $response->getStatusCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, I added verify=>false:

```
    $url="jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
    $client = \Drupal::httpClient(); 
    $post_data = $form_state->cleanValues()->getValues(); 
    $response = $client->request('POST', $url,
[ 'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'], 
'form_params' => $post_data, 
'verify'=>false, ]); 
    $body = $response->getBody()->getContents(); 
    $status = $response->getStatusCode(); 
    dsm($body); 
    dsm($status);
```